# Many Questions versus Many Answers

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers

I have noticed at times that there are some users who have never asked a single question, yet (very skillfully) answered hundreds (or thousands) of questions. By so doing they naturally accrue a great deal of reputation. As someone without a massive amount of rep, but someone who also wants to be a contributing member of MSE, I feel silly asking too many questions and have avoided such. I instead have focused my efforts on answering questions.

Can we say that it is the mark of a prolific user to have done no asking, only answering? I think of users such as [amWhy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy), [Andre Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andre-nicolas), and [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) (to name a few I personally encounter) who between them have about 20,000 or so answers and only 3 questions. Can someone become a legend and also ask a lot of questions?

Comment: I have a deja vu. Wasn't this question asked some months ago?

Comment: Maybe. I couldn't find it. I wasn't the one that asked it if it was. Find it and we can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Asaf I also have deja vu. [This one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/) maybe?

Comment: Yes, I would say that the link given by Grigory is a better version of my same question.

Answer (score 6):

> Don't worry so much about it!

You are over thinking it. It doesn't matter whether or not you ask a lot of questions. Personally I have used this site to ask several questions because I know that this is a good place to get quality answers. So, if you have a (good) question that fits well with this site, just ask it. The whole point is that we are helping each other learn math. The focus of this site is not about becoming legends or become online celebrities. It would be absurd if you held back a question because you [insert your reason] when getting an answer might actually help you.

Also remember that when you ask questions, then answers given might also benefit other users. I for sure have enjoyed greatly reading questions/answers.

I hardly doubt that anyone will consider you of "less value" because you ask questions. Asking questions isn't (IMO) of less value than providing answers.

(If you would like to be known here, then I suggest participating in meta and by raising flags and the other ways that you can contribute besides answering questions. There are several low-rep users that I respect simply because of their involvement on the site in general.)

(Also remember that you can get a decent amount of reputation from asking).